# Discord.py Bot Ban a Person

Tags: discord.py

Is there a way we can ban a person from using the bot's commands. Basically giving that particular person a Bot Ban!

Discord.py

Answer (score 0):

Make a ban command, then when the ban command is run instead of banning the person you give them a banned role, so whenever a command is run you can check if someone has that role and if they do the command wont work

Answer (score 0):

You just can simply store the banned user's ids in any way you Prefer (list, json, txt file, or any database), then when the user uses a command the bot will check if the user's id has stored or not.

You can also make a command that adds users ids to the list But keep in your mind that the new ids are not stored forever, in other words, if you turned off the bot, the data will disappear.

**Simple example:**

```py
#stored ids 
BANNED_USERS = [1234567890, 0987654321]


@client.command()
async def check(ctx):
  #check if the user is banned
  if ctx.author.id in BANNED_USERS:
    await ctx.send("you are banned from using this command")
  #if the user is not banned
  else:
    await ctx.send("you are allowed to use this command")

@client.command()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  BANNED_USERS.append(member.id)
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has been added to the blacklist")
```

**If you want to use the .txt file way, here is a Simple example:**

`By this way the user id will be stored in the text file that means if you turned off your bot, the banned users They'll keep stored unlike the list one`

```py
@client.command()
async def check(ctx):
  file =  open("banned.txt", "r")
  members_banned = file.readlines()
  if str(ctx.author.id) in members_banned:
    await ctx.send("you are not allowed to use my commands")
  else:
    await ctx.send("you are allowed to use my commands")
  file.close()

@client.command()
async def blacklist(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  file =  open("banned.txt", "a")
  file.write(member.id)
  file.close()
  await ctx.send(f"{member} has been added to the blacklist")
```